# Can't override root styles of Typography from Materil-UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, user-interface

Here is my small sandbox only with Material-UI:

In this case my styling don't work as i expect

```
import React from 'react'
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Typography className={classes.text}>Hello world</Typography>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Result (https://ibb.co/S74pq0m)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using material UI theme structure or are not aware of it so try to read about createTheme so you can use it globally https://mui.com/customization/typography/

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    body2: {
        fontSize: 30
    }
  },
});
export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className="App">
        <Typography variant="body2">Hello World</Typography>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```