# Override Typography varient styles in MUI v5

Tags: css, material-ui

I have a similar, but different issue to [Can't override root styles of Typography from Materil-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69937055/cant-override-root-styles-of-typography-from-materil-ui)

in v4 I had a theme:

```
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'light'
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: ['Work Sans', 'sans-serif'].join(','),
    fontSize: 14,
    h1: {
      fontFamily: ['Rubik', 'sans-serif'].join(','),
      fontSize: 20
    },
    h2: {
      fontFamily: ['Rubik', 'sans-serif'].join(','),
      fontSize: 18
    },
    h3: {
      fontFamily: ['Rubik', 'sans-serif'].join(','),
      fontSize: 16
    },
    h4: {
      fontFamily: ['Rubik', 'sans-serif'].join(','),
      fontSize: 16
    }
  }
});
```

This happily overrode the font size of the `<Typography variant='h2'>h2 heading</Typography>`

In the upgrade to v5, this override no longer works

I have also tried to add a components section to the theme

```
  components: {
    MuiTypography: {
      styleOverrides: {
        h2: {
          color: 'red',
          fontSize: '18px'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This does not work either.

I have noted that a new class is added to the HTML that overrides all previous CSS

What is needed so that all Typography variants are overrident as per v4?
[Extra class added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS5HI.png)
This is not in v4 HTML

Answer (score 3):

Using style overrides you can override a variant as follows:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTypography: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'h2' }, /* component props */
          style: {
            /* your style here: */
            color: 'red',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
```

This worked for me. I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

I have figured the issue.
In `app.ts` I had

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/styles';
```

when it should have been

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the above and still no change. It was only when i also removed any MUI V4 references in my package.json when it got sorted it out for me. Hopefully that helps someone :)